# gmail client, rendering attached image and the second as noname attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

im sending html email with images as attachments. Everything is fine with all other images but with the one - that is used two times as a background - top and bottom border, it is also visible as a noname attachment.

In the situation where there is only one image with the same source such situation doesnt take place.

Is there any way I can do sth with this ?

```
<img alt="" src="cid:[STATICIMAGE:/mailings/shadow.jpg]" width="500" height="9" />

bla bla bla

<img alt="" src="cid:[STATICIMAGE:/mailings/shadow.jpg]" width="500" height="9"  />
```

Comment: try giving different id's to the images.

Comment: attribute id ? for example img src="..." alt="..." id="X" <-